# Custom SUMPRODUCT()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, weighted, sumproduct

I have the following table:

[image]

My objective is to spread out the 10,000 units across the 5 months, given the weightings below each month. The row adjacent the 10,000 is my best attempt at getting this (I have spent a few hours on this). The yellow is what I am after.

The logic I have tried to use to get the calculation is as follows: Calculate the even spread across the months (in this example 10,000 / 5 = 2,000 = X). Multiply each month weighting to get the weighted amount (in this example to get M2 = 1,600 and M4 = 3,000: X + (X * M2 weighting) etc). You can then take the total 10,000 minus the summation of these which will give you 5,400, which you can then distribute across the months don't don't have a weighting. There must be an easy way to do this with a `SUMPRODUCT` but I can't seem to figure it out.

My best attempt so far is this:

`=IF(B3=0,SUMPRODUCT(ABS((10000/5)*$B3:$F3)),(10000/5)+((10000/5)*B3))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

[image]

Formula in `B3`:

```
=IF(B$2=0,($A3-SUMPRODUCT(($B2:$F2<>0)*(($A3/5)*(1+$B2:$F2))))/COUNTIF($B2:$F2,0),($A3/5)*(1+B$2))
```

Drag right.

Logic:

- `=IF(B$2=0,<true>,<false>)` - Check if cell above equals zero
- If above is false (so other than 0) then: `($A3/5)*(1+B$2)` - First divide `(10000/5)` and multiply that outcome by `(1-<percentage>)`
- If `IF` yields true - Check which cells in range are other than zero and multiply by the same logic as per step 2. The sum gained with `SUMPRODUCT` can then be deducted from 10000 and devided by the count of cells that actually do hold zero (hence the `COUNTIF`).

Comment: Amazing @JvdV thanks, that works like a charm. Mind explaining your logic behind that?

Comment: Not sure if I did explain it very well @Dean, but I'm glad it works well for you.